# How can I handle empty query parameters in Vapor routes handler

Tags: swift, vapor

I would like to handle this HTTP GET request http://localhost:8080/route?wsdl and return a static file

I have started with this route handler
app.get("route") { req throws -> EventLoopFuture in

```
      // req.query.get(String.self, at: "wsdl") throws an DecodingError
      // I would like to check if the empty query parameter wsdl is present
      // once I can check for the empty query parameter, I would use this for an if  
      //statement and in the case it is present return a static file
      // then only a static file must be returned
        return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(
            req.fileio.streamFile(at: "file.wsdl") 
          )
    }
}
```

I have tried these routes as well, but no success:
app.get("route?wsdl")
-> this is not invoked, was probably not supposed to work

app.get("route",":wsdl")
-> this is not invoked

Answer (score 1):

```
// route handler   
app.get("route") { req throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> in
        if let query = req.url.query,
            query.count == 4,
           query == "wsdl" {
            return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(
                req.fileio.streamFile(at: "file.wsdl")
              )
            }
        else {
            throw Abort(.notFound)
        }
   }
```